# ASP.Net Core specifying multiple content-types with response compression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

What is the correct way to specify that your API can return compressed responses via Swagger/SwashbuckleUI in ASP.NET Core 3.x?

The goal is to support both non-compressed and compressed responses, giving the calling user the flexibility to choose what they want via their `Accept-Encoding` header. This is a hard requirement as one consuming team is limited in what libraries they can use to make the API calls. The code itself is doing what is required, but I can't get Swagger/SwashbuckleUI to reflect this feature in the documentation.

Given the following example:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceConnection services)
{
    services.Configure<BrotliCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal;
    });

    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider();
        options.EnableForHttps = true;
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvrironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/dev/mycontroller")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "My Swagger Name")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseDTO>> GetAll()
    {
        var dbResults = _repository.Model.GetAll();

        if (dbResults != null)
        {
            return Ok(dbResults.ToResponseDTOs());
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that I need to add another string to the `ProducesAttribute`:

`[Produces("application/json", "br")]`

So that Swagger/SwashbuckleUI would display that, similar to examples I have seen for dual json/xml support.  However, when I try to build the project after adding the "br" string to the `ProducesAttribute` I get:

`System.FormatException` "The header contains invalid values at index 0: 'br'"

from the `MapControllers()` call in the `Configure` method on startup.

Comment: Transport compression, is a transport problem, not an API problem. Add the right middleware to optionally compress the stream.

Comment: The middleware (AddResponseCompression(), and UseResponseCompression()) have been added, and are working. The issue is describing this feature in the documentation

Comment: It doesn't work like that. `Produces` reports `Content-Type`, while what you are looking for is `Content-Encoding`. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding. It's something, I believe, the server decides to do. You can't tell before hand if it's going to happen. You have to look at the headers of the response to know what it was encoded with. Besides, it's something that the caller doesn't need to know about since it's handled by the HTTP client.